# Understanding new Java syntax and reason behind it

Tags: java

These days I am looking into codebase of a new project. It has multiple classes defined with similar signature:

```
public abstract class ClassB<A extends ClassA<A,B,C>, A extends ClassB<A,B,C>, C extends ClassC<A,B,C>> extends AnotherClass<A> {}
```

I could not get my head around it. Specially `class aliases`(I guess thats what it is called).
More keen on understanding how it improves over old way of doing things.

Comment: You don't seem to be asking a direct question. Perhaps you should study some information on Java generics, like: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/ .

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ClassB<A, B, C> extends AnotherClass<A> {}
```

Where:

- Generic **A** must **extend** `ClassA<A, B, C>`
- Generic **B** must **extend** `ClassB<A, B, C>`
- Generic **C** must **extend** `ClassC<A, B, C>`